# Comparing two columns from different tables of different types in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

There is a column that exists in 2 tables. In table 1, this column contains values in binary form (`int`), `1` and `0`, while the other table contains the column in form `'Y'` and `'N'`.

Essentially I need to display rows in table 1 that contain values that are different from values in table 2 for that column. How do I compute 1 to Y and 0 to N for comparison?

Example:

Table 1:

```
DateRecorded SchoolName StudentName isAbsent hasPassed
------------ ---------- ----------- -------- ---------
2011-04-03   ABC        John        Y        Y
2011-04-05   ABC        John        N        Y
```

Table 2:

```
DateRecorded SchoolName StudentName isAbsent hasPassed
------------ ---------- ----------- -------- ---------
2011-04-03   ABC        John        0        1
2011-04-05   ABC        John        0        1
```

Should return row:

```
2011-04-03   ABC        John        Y        Y
```

from Table 1 as this row is conflicting with the same row in Table 2.

Comment: First of all, it's either SQL Server 2008 or 2012,there is no SQL Server 2010. Apart from that, do you have some other column on those tables in common?, as in for the same value of column1 you need to see if your binary column has the same value on both tables?

Comment: hi lamak thanks for the comment. yeah my mistake, its 2008 R2 that i am using. actually i have 2 tables that are supposedly the same tables but 1 table contains all data in 1 and 0 format whereas the other table contains all data in Y and N format. Now I need to find out if there is a row containing conflicting data. For e.g. i need to find out, if the column is listed as '1' in table 1 and 'N' in table 2.

Comment: @user1505695 To give you an accurate answer, we need to know more information about your tables. Please post your table schema, and perhaps a sample data-set.

Comment: Sure:  Table 1:  DateRecorded SchoolName StudentName isAbsent hasPassed  2011-04-03 ABC John Y Y  2011-04-05 ABC John N Y  Table 2:  DateRecorded SchoolName StudentName isAbsent hasPassed  2011-04-03 ABC John 0 1  2011-04-05 ABC John 0 1  should return row: 2011-04-03 ABC John Y Y as this row is conflicting with Table 2 results

Comment: hmm still trying to format it... :/ not sure why it's not working...

Comment: You should add the sample to your post (using the *Edit* link underneath). It would be easier to format it there, and besides, that would be the most appropriate place for it. Use 4-space indentation and insert an empty line after the preceding paragraph.

Comment: In order to compare the rows, you should know which row in Table 2 to compare to which Table 1 row. Or, in other words, there should be a *key* column (or column set). What are the keys in these two tables?

Comment: primary key is dateRecorded and studentName together (this is based on the appropriate business requirements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1

EXCEPT

SELECT 
    daterecorded,
    schoolname,
    studentname,
    CASE isAbsent WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' WHEN 0 THEN 'N' END AS isAbsent,
    CASE hasPassed WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' WHEN 0 THEN 'N' END AS hasPassed
FROM tbl2
```

---

[SQL-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01574/2/0)

Comment: hey zane, thanks for the effort. i tried that but it produced a very different result with more entries than my initial data. i have added a comment to help better understand my situation. thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user1505695 Edited solution, try now

Comment: zane i shall try out your solution and get bk to you. thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ah, this is just brilliant! This way you don't even need to know which are key columns.

Comment: @AndriyM, Thanks. I still wish we had `SELECT * EXCLUDING col1, col2` though!! =P